# how to embed html code inside a component of an rcp application

Tags: eclipse-rcp

can we embed/place HTML content inside the setText() like setText("some html code here");method of a label component in rcp.
i knew that the label widget of swings has this capability.Is there a way to do the same with rcp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have basic HTML you can use [FormText](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/forms/widgets/FormText.html) from `org.eclipse.ui.forms` package. For full support of HTML use [SWT Browser](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/package-summary.html) (I know, it's a bit overkill).